# how to solve this run time error NsInvalidargument

Tags: ios, scrollview

I'm a beginner to iOS. In my code I am getting a crash when trying to call a method which adds the scroll view. The crash is,

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController addscrollview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

This method is present in my `ViewController` class, check the declaration,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate> { 
    UIScrollView *myscrollview; 
} 

-(void)addscrollview; 
property (retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *myscrollview;
```

What can be the reason for the crash and how can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have a method called addscrollview? If so, is it spelled that way with no capital letters?

Comment: i have amethod and it is spelled correctly

Answer (score 1):

`addscrollview` There is no method defined in the viewcontroller with that name,See if such a method exist in viewcontroller.